# MongoDB aggregate query for multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mern

Let me first of all explain the situation. I have made advanced search which is used to search posts and profiles. I have made switch button which shows post search or profile search. After receiving all the details on the server. I have made this query:

```
await Profile.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                {"company": {$regex: profile.company}},
                {"skills": {$all: profile.skills}},
                {"experience.company" :{$in: [ profile.experience.company]}}
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $skip: req.params.page ? req.params.page - 1 : 0 // make sure this can't be -1
    },
    {
        $limit: 11
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "user",
            localField: "user",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "user"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$user"
    }
])
```

But lets say company is undefined and gives me the following error $regex must be a string. How to search about this fields that are defined or not empty string? Also I'm not sure if that piece of code is right:

```
{"experience.company" :{$in: [ profile.experience.company]}}
```

And the next question is how search for user.name company and skills at once? Should I lookup first and then match or what? (Sorry about this questions, but I'm new to MongoDB)

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the `$regex` error when comparing the `undefined` fields, you can filter the fields at the beginning.

**Example:**

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match:{
      company: {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**"*And the next question is how search for user.name company and skills at once?*"**

You can do it in one aggregation pipeline at a time. That doesn't matter. but related to which query will be placed at the beginning of the pipeline depends on your data structure and what you are looking for.

Comment: Hello! I can you give me an example with your code about $exists ( with mine fields company skills..). Lets say I have an Profile collection with company and skills and user collections with name in it I want to compare search queries to that and if any of these 3 match I want to return. Also is there any possible way to count them so I can return them sorted by best match and then less and less and is this valid code: `{"experience.company" :{$in: [ profile.experience.company]}}` because returns all the profiles(match them all or something like that) Thank you!